# Sybase SQLAnywhere matching phone numbers formatted different ways

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have a table with a phone number varchar field. This field has phone numbers that are formatted many different ways. 999-999-9999 or (999) 999-9999 and so on. I have a phone number that I am trying to find which is formatted like this: "9999999999". I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT …
WHERE replace(PHO_PhoneNumber, "[^\\d]", “") = “9999999999”
```

Basically remove all non digits from the field and then compare.

Is there such a function "replace" that uses regex, or is there a better way of trying to find this number when the phone number field can have many different formatting characters in it ? I have no control over how phone numbers get entered into this table.

Thanks,

Warren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of SQL Anywhere you're using, but as of version 11.0, SQL Anywhere supports the REGEXP operator in the where clause, so you could do something like:

```
select ...
where PHO_PhoneNumber regexp '\(?\d{3}\)?-?\d{3}-?\d{4}'
```

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: I think it is version 11. Is everything between single quotes just straight regex ? No special escaping needed ?

Comment: Pretty much, though it seems there are always slight syntax differences between almost any two regexp implementations. The v11 docs are here http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1101/en/dbreference_en11/regexp-search-condition.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Sybase has such a function.  You could write one.  However, the "special" characters in phone numbers are typically:  "()+- ".  You can use multiple replaces for these:

```
WHERE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(PHO_PhoneNumber, ' ', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), '+', ''), '-', '') = '9999999999'
```